# d3.js -- Axis label help (from v3 to v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am taking an online tutorial on D3.js. Since the version 4 recently came out, there are some things in the old version that wont support in version 4. I've been looking at their github to look for comparison.

Anyway I am stumped on this part of lesson -- labeling the axis on a graph.

Here's a working code in version 3:

[Version3](http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/JRWvQQ)

Here's my attempt in version 4:

[Version4--not working](http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/amwNwr?editors=0010)

**version 3**

```
var data = [
    {key: "Jelly", value: 60, date: "2014/01/01" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 58, date: "2014/01/02" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/03" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/04" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/05" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 55, date: "2014/01/06" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/07" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/08" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 54, date: "2014/01/09" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/10" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/11" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/12" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/13" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/14" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/15" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 47, date: "2014/01/16" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/17" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 45, date: "2014/01/18" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/19" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/20" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 37, date: "2014/01/21" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 36, date: "2014/01/22" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/23" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/24" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 42, date: "2014/01/25" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/26" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/27" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/28" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/29" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/30" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/31" }
];
var w = 800;
var h = 450;
var margin = {
    top: 58,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 80,
    right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "chart")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
var chart = svg.append("g")
            .classed("display", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.date);
            return date;
        }))
        .range([0,width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return d.value;
        })])
        .range([height,0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(d3.time.days, 7)
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d"));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5);
function plot(params){
    this.append("g")
        .classed("x axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(params.axis.x);
    this.append("g")
        .classed("y axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(params.axis.y);
    //enter()
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .data(params.data)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .classed("point", true)
            .attr("r", 2);
    //update
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.date);
            return x(date);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })
    //exit()
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .data(params.data)
        .exit()
        .remove();
}
plot.call(chart, {
    data: data,
    axis: {
        x: xAxis,
        y: yAxis
    }
});
```

**version 4**

```
var data = [
    {key: "Jelly", value: 60, date: "2014/01/01" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 58, date: "2014/01/02" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/03" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/04" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/05" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 55, date: "2014/01/06" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/07" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/08" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 54, date: "2014/01/09" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/10" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/11" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/12" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/13" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/14" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/15" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 47, date: "2014/01/16" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/17" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 45, date: "2014/01/18" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/19" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/20" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 37, date: "2014/01/21" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 36, date: "2014/01/22" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/23" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/24" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 42, date: "2014/01/25" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/26" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/27" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/28" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/29" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/30" },
    {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/31" }
];
var w = 800;
var h = 450;
var margin = {
    top: 58,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 80,
    right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "chart")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
var chart = svg.append("g")
            .classed("display", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
              var date = dateParser(d.date);
              return date
            }))
            .range([0, width])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
              return d.value
            })])
            .range([height, 0])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(7)

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

function plot(params){
  //create axis for x and y
    this.append("g")
        .classed("x axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(params.axis.x);
    this.append("g")
        .classed("y axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(params.axis.y);

    //enter()
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .data(params.data)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .classed("point", true)
            .attr("r", 2);
    //update
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.date);
            return x(date);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })
    //exit()
    this.selectAll(".point")
        .data(params.data)
        .exit()
        .remove();
}

plot.call(chart, {
    data: data,
  axis: {
    x: xAxis,
    y: yAxis
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using d3.v4 has some changes from the previous version. If you have a date field in axis, go with [d3.scaleTime()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleTime). Parse the date with the date parser.

```js
var data = [
 {key: "Jelly", value: 60, date: "2014/01/01" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 58, date: "2014/01/02" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/03" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/04" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/05" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 55, date: "2014/01/06" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/07" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/08" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 54, date: "2014/01/09" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 57, date: "2014/01/10" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/11" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 59, date: "2014/01/12" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 56, date: "2014/01/13" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 52, date: "2014/01/14" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/15" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 47, date: "2014/01/16" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 48, date: "2014/01/17" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 45, date: "2014/01/18" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/19" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/20" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 37, date: "2014/01/21" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 36, date: "2014/01/22" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/23" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/24" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 42, date: "2014/01/25" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/26" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 43, date: "2014/01/27" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 41, date: "2014/01/28" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/29" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 40, date: "2014/01/30" },
 {key: "Jelly", value: 39, date: "2014/01/31" }
];
var w = 300;
var h = 250;
var margin = {
 top: 58,
 bottom: 100,
 left: 80,
 right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("id", "chart")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

var chart = svg.append("g")
   .classed("display", true)
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y/%M/%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ var date = dateParser(d.date); return date }))
            .range([0, width])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
              return d.value
            })])
            .range([height, 0])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(7)

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

function plot(params){
  //create axis for x and y
 this.append("g")
  .classed("x axis", true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(params.axis.x);
 this.append("g")
  .classed("y axis", true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .call(params.axis.y);
  
 //enter()
 this.selectAll(".point")
  .data(params.data)
  .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .classed("point", true)
   .attr("r", 2);
 //update
 this.selectAll(".point")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
   var date = dateParser(d.date);
   return x(date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){
   return y(d.value);
  })
 //exit()
 this.selectAll(".point")
  .data(params.data)
  .exit()
  .remove();
}

plot.call(chart, {
 data: data,
  axis: {
    x: xAxis,
    y: yAxis
  }
});
```

```css
   body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #chart{
    background-color: #F5F2EB;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
   }
   .bar{
    fill: purple;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
   .bar-label{
    fill: black;
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
   }
   .axis path,
   .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
   .gridline path,
   .gridline line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking back at the code, I forgot to format it

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(7)
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d"));